# Solve the boundary-value problem with Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Solve
$$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2} - sU = A, \qquad (0<x<1)$$
subject to the boundary conditions
$$\frac{dU}{dx}(0) = 0, \qquad U(1) = 0.$$

The part I'm stuck on is that after taking Laplace transforms, I have a $U(0)$ term that I cannot evaluate because the boundary condition gave me $U(1)$. What should I do in this case?

I already know that the correct answer is
$$U =\frac{A}{s} \left( \frac{\cosh\left(\sqrt s  x\right)}{\cosh \left(\sqrt s \right)} - 1 \right).$$

Comment: It's kinda weird how you are given $U(1)$ despite it is given that $0 < x < 1$. After getting $U(x)$ in terms of $x$ and $U(0)$, plug in $x=1$ you can solve for $U(0)$.

Comment: What you give as correct answer is a solution of ODE: $\frac{d^2U}{dx^2} \color{red}{-} sU = A$

Answer (score 0):

**This is a track not a complete answer**

For clarity lets denote $V=\mathcal{L}(U)$ the Laplace transfrom of $U$.

We have :

$$ \mathcal{L}(U'') : p \to  p^2V(s)−pU(0)−U′(0)$$

So the equation rewrites with $U'(0)=0$ :

$$ p^2V(s)−pU(0) + sV = \dfrac{A}{p}  $$

So

$$ (p^3+sp)V(s)=p^2U(0)+A$$

Hence

$$ V(s)=\dfrac{A+p^2U(0)}{p^3+sp}$$

$$ V(s)=\dfrac{A+p^2U(0)}{p^3+sp}$$

Integrating back (inverse Laplace) and considering $B\triangleq U(0)$ with the know formulas online here for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform